# Scroll only single listfield in multiple listfields blackberry

Tags: blackberry, listfield

I'm new to blackberry and I've a question, I've 3 listfields in a row like

[--------One--------][--Two--][--Three--]

but when I scroll single one, every one scrolls!, how do I restrict scroll of others when focused one is scrolling?

**EDIT**

```
// ListFields
HorizontalFieldManager hfmMain = new HorizontalFieldManager();

HorizontalFieldManager hfmFist = new HorizontalFieldManager(FIELD_LEFT);
hfmFist.add(myListView);

HorizontalFieldManager hfmSecond = new HorizontalFieldManager();
hfmSecond.add(hizabListView);

HorizontalFieldManager hfmThird = new HorizontalFieldManager();
hfmThird.add(paraListView);

hfmMain.add(hfmFist);
hfmMain.add(hfmSecond);
hfmMain.add(hfmThird);

add(hfmMain);
```

[image]

Comment: @Nate, screenshot added, each listfield should scroll separately and 1st listfields' height is different than others and 2nd, 3rds' are same.

Comment: It appears that the `HorizontalFieldManager hfmListSurah` has focus and thus all 3 listfields scroll at the same time because in essence you are scrolling over the `HorizontalFieldManager hfmListSurah` and not over the `Listfield`. Use `Focusable - Field style bit to indicate whether or not the field is focusable.`

Comment: @Sarah, yes each listfiels' index is focused separately when I click, so how do I add managers separately for each listfield, when I simply add to screen just first listfield shows up.

Comment: You can call one `HorizontanlFieldManager (HFM)` and place 3 `HFM` into it each containing a `ListField`. This would keep the focus separate.

Comment: placed each listfied in hfm and again placed every hfm in MainHFM and add to screen and still all of them scroll :(

Comment: if you can share that code it will help investigate the issue further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is that you need to disable vertical scrolling for the `Screen` that contains all these managers and fields.

**Then,** you can create one horizontal field manager.  And then, three vertical field managers.  Put each list in its own vertical field manager, and then all three vertical field managers go into the horizontal field manager.

Here's a simple prototype that I tested:

```java
public class ListFocusScreen extends MainScreen implements ListFieldCallback {

   private ObjectListField list1;
   private ListField list2;
   private ListField list3;
   private Bitmap icon2;   // for list 2 cell background
   private Bitmap icon3;   // for list 3 cell background

   public ListFocusScreen() {
      // Do NOT allow vertical scrolling at the Screen level!!
      super(MainScreen.NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL | MainScreen.NO_VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR);

      // A container for the "row" of three side-by-side lists
      HorizontalFieldManager hfm = new HorizontalFieldManager(Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH);

      // Do create a vertical field manager for each list, that scrolls
      VerticalFieldManager vfm1 = new VerticalFieldManager(Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLL | Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR) {
         protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
            super.sublayout(2 * Display.getWidth() / 3, maxHeight);   // 2/3 width
         }         
      };
      VerticalFieldManager vfm2 = new VerticalFieldManager(Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLL | Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR) {
         protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
            super.sublayout(Display.getWidth() / 6, maxHeight);       // 1/6 width
         }         
      };
      VerticalFieldManager vfm3 = new VerticalFieldManager(Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLL | Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR) {
         protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
            super.sublayout(Display.getWidth() / 6, maxHeight);       // 1/6 width
         }         
      };

      Object[] listData1 = new Object[24];
      for (int i = 0; i < listData1.length; i++) {
         // generate fake data for list1
         listData1[i] = String.valueOf(i) + ". Click to Download";
      }
      list1 = new ObjectListField();
      list1.set(listData1);

      list2 = new ListField();
      list2.setCallback(this);
      icon2 = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("octagon.png");
      list2.setSize(15);

      list3 = new ListField();
      list3.setCallback(this);
      icon3 = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("frame.png");
      list3.setSize(15);

      vfm1.add(list1);
      vfm2.add(list2);
      vfm3.add(list3);
      hfm.add(vfm1);
      hfm.add(vfm2);
      hfm.add(vfm3);
      add(hfm);
   }

   public void drawListRow(ListField listField, Graphics graphics, int index,
         int y, int width) {
      // this same method will be used for custom drawing of both lists 2 and 3
      final int PAD = 4;
      String text = (String)get(listField, index);
      if (listField == list2) {
         graphics.drawBitmap(0, y, width, width, icon2, 0, 0);
         graphics.drawText(text, PAD, y + PAD);
      } else if (listField == list3) {
         graphics.drawBitmap(0, y, width, width, icon3, 0, 0);
         graphics.drawText(text, PAD, y + PAD);
      }      
   }

   public Object get(ListField listField, int index) {
      // TODO: normally, get this value from a vector of actual 
      //  data for each list
      return String.valueOf(index);
   }

   public int getPreferredWidth(ListField listField) {
      return Display.getWidth() / 6;
   }

   public int indexOfList(ListField listField, String prefix, int start) {
      return -1;  // no search support
   }   
}
```

### Results

[image]

As you can see, I was able to get each list scrolling vertically, *independently*.

Answer (score 1):

You have several list fields into one screen manager and when you scroll down and when this manager is selected, then the scroll event is being sent to all these fields. And all of them are scrolling simultaneously.

I would separate every listfield into its own manager.

Comment: Thanks Rafael, can you please show me an example how to do so?

Comment: Here's tutorials on screen managers and UI: http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/29251/Manager_1579416_11.jsp